# WCF Server Faulting

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Here is the error that I am getting:

> The communication object, 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for
>   communication because it is in the Faulted state.

I have a service using WCF trying to send a string of length 86,284 to another service. Both services have these settings (I'm using a NetTcpBinding):

```
MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000;
MaxBufferPoolSize = 100000;
MaxBufferSize = 100000;
MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483646
```

I also have:

```
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
```

I am trying to use that to get some sort of useful error message to go off of, but for some reason I get the same thing. It is possible that I just don't understand how to access the helpful error message. I have also tried logging the service, but it gave the same error.

I have drilled it down so that I know that the service faults when I send this string to the other service. I have confirmed that it works 100% of the time sending another string that is just 6392 characters long. This is why I thought those properties might fix this. If anyone has any ideas or tips, it would be very appreciated.

Wow I finally get an error message:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

Sooooo somehow I'm not setting this property correctly. I create the NetTcpBinding and then set the property that way. Not sure why that wouldn't work.

EDIT: Solved

Comment: Are you running the service in IIS, I know that can also set message size limits.

Comment: No, it isn't a web service. I'm setting most properties programattically, but otherwise I would be doing it in the App.config

Answer (score 0):

Edit (question changed): Check the ReaderQuotas on your NetTcpBinding. There are some additional max lengths in there.

C# uses UTF-16 to store strings, which means one character != one byte. Your 86k character string is most likely more than 100k bytes, which would exceed the message size quotas specified. You could try using Encoding.GetBytes() to check the actual size in bytes of your string.

Comment: I was already logging the byte array length before I convert it to a string. It is 64712

Comment: Seems like the ReaderQuotas might be a possibility, I will let you know.

Comment: I changed ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength, but I got the same issue. Why wouldn't that fix it if I'm sending over a string? I would doubt changing the MaxArrayLength or any of the other properties would fix it if that didn't. That's the thing is I know it has to do with the length, but none of the solutions are fixing it...

Comment: Make sure you are setting the reader quotas property correctly. "binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10000000" won't actually work -- see http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Editors_IDEs/Q_23510900.html

Comment: That link looks like he is trying to set the ReaderQuotas property, which is read-only. I didn't have any issue setting the MaxStringContentLength specifically. The error message I got also explicitly says to change the MaxReceivedMessageSize, so I'm curious if this is what I should focus on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look and see if the collection count limit is being surpassed.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureServiceBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Also, [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) is some documentation on increasing the maximum allowed request size in iis.

The exception about the communication faulted is likely due to you using session. Once you get an exception you will continue to receive the error until you re-authenticate or refresh the session.

Answer (score 0):

For the two services that were communicating with eachother, one of them was hosted within another windows service. I changed the MaxReceivedMessageSize of this other service and it fixed the issue. It needed this property set on both of the windows services and actually did not need it on the one hosted within the other.